# Upload and convert Large videos using video module

Tags: 7, files

I am trying to develop Drupal 7 website which will allow users to upload large video files. As the files are too big (min 1.5GB), i am converting them to .flv format by using video (7.x-2.11) module with ffmpeg (version:N-67205-g61e42c1) configured. I am hosting this website internally on Windows server 2012.

Now, My problem is when i upload my video and convert it on node save, ffmpeg takes 100% CPU which affecting my whole website performance. I checked this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11107206/how-to-restrict-ffmpeg-to-use-only-50-of-my-cpu) but it's not helping me to much.

My main requirement is to convert all videos to .flv format by using this video module or any other method. So, can anyone point me to proper direction to implement this kind of website?
Thank You :)

Comment: any update here? looking solution for a similar issue. Need to convert all videos uploaded to .mp4